# How can I show selected option results

Tags: php

I have this form will add total cost of the selected items but I need show what has been selected at the result. How can I display selected options at result?
I need show buyer of exactly what was ordered, in a table.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<head>
    <title> Light Bulbs Sales Form </title>
</head>

<body>
    <h2> Welcome to Light Bulbs Sales Form </h2>
    <form action="index.php" method="post">
        <p>
            <label> Buyer's Name:
                <input type="text" name="name" size="30" /> 
            </label>
        <p/>
        <table>
            <tr>
                <th></th>
                <th>Product Name</th>
                <th>Price</th>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td><input type="checkbox" name="b[]" value="2.39"/></td>
                <td> Four 25-watt light bulbs </td>
                <td> $2.39 </td>                    
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td><input type="checkbox" name="b[]" value="4.29"/></td>
                <td> Eight 25-watt light bulbs </td>
                <td> $4.29 </td>                       
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td><input type="checkbox" name="b[]" value="3.95"/></td>
                <td> Four 25-watt long-life light bulbs </td>
                <td> $3.95 </td>   
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td><input type="checkbox" name="b[]" value="7.49"/></td>
                <td> Eight 25-watt long-life light bulbs </td>
                <td> $7.49 </td>     
            </tr>
        </table>  
        <h3>Payment Method</h3>
            <p>
                <label><input type="radio" name="payment" value="Visa"/>Visa</label>
                <br/>
                <label><input type="radio" name="payment" value="Master Card"/>Master Card</label>
                <br/>
                <label><input type="radio" name="payment" value="Discover"/>Discover</label>
                <br/>
            </p>
            <p>
                <input type="submit" value="Submit Order"/>
                <input type="reset" value="Clear Order Form"/>
            </p>
        </form>
</body>
</html>
```

This is my php code:

```html
<?php
$name=$_POST["name"];
$bulbs=$_POST["b"];
$pmode=$_POST["payment"];

$total=0;
for($i=0;$i<sizeof($bulbs);$i++)
{
    $tax=$bulbs[$i]*0.062;
    $total=$total+$bulbs[$i]+$tax;
    $totalcost=number_format((float)$total, 2, '.', '');
}

print "Your name is: $name <br>";
print "Your total cost is: $totalcost <br>";
print "Your chosen method of payment is: $pmode";

?>
```

Comment: What is not working as expected ?

Answer (score 0):

Convert according to your one. And try this one. You can print selected option values as follows.

HTML & PHP:

```
<form action="php_checkbox.php" method="post">
<label class="heading">Select One:</label>
<input type="checkbox" name="check_list[]" value="4.29"><label>4.29</label>
<input type="checkbox" name="check_list[]" value="3.25"><label>3.25</label>
</form>
<?php


if(isset($_POST['submit'])){

if(!empty($_POST['check_list'])) {

$checked_count = count($_POST['check_list']);
echo "Selected values ".$checked_count." option(s): <br/>";

foreach($_POST['check_list'] as $selected) {
echo "<p>".$selected ."</p>";

}
else{
echo "<b>Please Select Atleast One Option.</b>";
}
}
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try this:

**html code**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<head>
    <title> Light Bulbs Sales Form </title>
</head>

<body>
    <h2> Welcome to Light Bulbs Sales Form </h2>
    <form action="action.php" method="post">
        <p>
            <label> Buyer's Name:
                <input type="text" name="name" size="30" /> 
            </label>
        <p/>
        <table>
            <tr>
                <th></th>
                <th>Product Name</th>
                <th>Price</th>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td><input type="checkbox" name="b[]" value="2.39"/></td>
                <td> Four 25-watt light bulbs </td>
                <td> $2.39 </td>                    
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td><input type="checkbox" name="b[]" value="4.29"/></td>
                <td> Eight 25-watt light bulbs </td>
                <td> $4.29 </td>                       
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td><input type="checkbox" name="b[]" value="3.95"/></td>
                <td> Four 25-watt long-life light bulbs </td>
                <td> $3.95 </td>   
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td><input type="checkbox" name="b[]" value="7.49"/></td>
                <td> Eight 25-watt long-life light bulbs </td>
                <td> $7.49 </td>     
            </tr>
        </table>  
        <h3>Payment Method</h3>
            <p>
                <label><input type="radio" name="payment" value="Visa"/>Visa</label>
                <br/>
                <label><input type="radio" name="payment" value="Master Card"/>Master Card</label>
                <br/>
                <label><input type="radio" name="payment" value="Discover"/>Discover</label>
                <br/>
            </p>
            <p>
                <input type="submit" value="Submit Order"/>
                <input type="reset" value="Clear Order Form"/>
            </p>
        </form>
</body>
</html>
```

**Php Code**

```
<?php
$name=$_POST["name"];
$bulbs=$_POST["b"];
$pmode=$_POST["payment"];
$select_val=$_POST["b"];
$total=0;
for($i=0;$i<sizeof($bulbs);$i++)
{
    $tax=$bulbs[$i]*0.062;
    $total=$total+$bulbs[$i]+$tax;
    $totalcost=number_format((float)$total, 2, '.', '');
}

echo "Selected Product value:<br>";
for ($j=0; $j <count($select_val) ; $j++) { 
    echo ($j+1).")".$select_val[$j]."<br>";
}

print "Your name is: $name <br>";
print "Your total cost is: $totalcost <br>";
print "Your chosen method of payment is: $pmode";

?>
```

Comment: Thank you for answer but on this code it shows selected items price but I need to show selected items itself how can I do that?

Answer (score 0):

using implode we can show what has been selected

```
           $select_val=$_POST["b"];
           $comma_separated = implode(",", $select_val);
           echo  $comma_separated ;
```

array_sum  adds all the values in the array and show the total

```
          echo "total  = " . array_sum($select_val) . "\n";
```